Can you sum two binary scores with different chance levels?
I designed an experiment, where outcome was measured by 2 tasks.

In the first task, participants chose which one of the two options
is correct.
In the second task, they chose which one of the three
options is correct.

Both tasks are scored binarily: 1 for choosing the correct option and 0 for choosing the other one(s).
Both tasks tap onto the same conceptual variable, so I'd like to create a sum score (Task 1 + Task 2), as a single measure for the outcome. But I have been warned that it may be wrong to sum binary scores that have different chance level. If so, what should I do?
The two scores have similar means (around 0.4) and standard deviations (around 0.5), if that is a concern.

You can certainly add them; it's still "number correct" for example, but of course in normal circumstance you wouldn't reasonably assume you're adding things that are identically distributed.

If you score both answers (1,0), as I assume, you may undervalue the 2nd question (which is harder to get correctly by dumb luck). But who says you need to score (1,0)? You could score the first question (2,0), and the 2nd (3,0); now you are weightibg the 2nd question a bit more heavily. But I think you can do even better. Why not score the first (1,-1), and the 2nd (2,-1). If all the subjects just randomly pick theitr answers, you would expect an average score of 0 (0=random). A positive average indicates a preponderance of correct answers, and reciprocally for negative scores.
Based on your means being negative (with (1,0) scoring), I suspect that your subjects generally pick the wrong answers (which may not be significant depending on your sample size)

Thank you so much for the idea of weighting! I think that makes much sense. It may be a stretch, but is there any literature or practical application that I can cite to justify this weighting? (Re the last point -- I have different conditions and the goal is to see how groups differ in the outcome; so the means<0.5 is good, suggesting room to improve)
